# .Net DataGridView Not Showing Changed Structure Until Second Run-Through

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView placed on the second tab of a tabbed form.  When the user clicks on the tab with the DGV, the following code fires:

```
    dgvItems.DataSource = Nothing
    If dgvItems.Columns.Contains("AddTrack") Then dgvItems.Columns.Remove("AddTrack")
    If dgvItems.Columns.Contains("ViewTrack") Then dgvItems.Columns.Remove("ViewTrack")
    If dgvItems.Columns.Contains("Carrier") Then dgvItems.Columns.Remove("Carrier")
    If dgvItems.Columns.Contains("ShipDate") Then dgvItems.Columns.Remove("ShipDate")
    If dgvItems.Columns.Contains("TrackingNo") Then dgvItems.Columns.Remove("TrackingNo")

    sql = "SOME SQL COMMAND"
    dgvItems.DataSource = GetPervasiveData(sql)

    Dim sqlTrack As String = ""
    Dim dtTrack As Data.DataTable

    Dim dcAdd As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
    dcAdd.Name = "AddTrack"
    dcAdd.Text = "Add Tracking"
    dcAdd.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true

    Dim dcTrack As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
    dcTrack.Name = "ViewTrack"
    dcTrack.Text = "Track"
    dcTrack.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true

    Dim dcCarrier As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    dcCarrier.Name= "Carrier"

    Dim dcShipDate As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    dcShipDate.Name= "ShipDate"
    dcShipDate.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"

    Dim dcTrackingNo As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    dcTrackingNo.Name= "TrackingNo"

    dgvItems.Columns.Add(dcAdd)
    dgvItems.Columns.Add(dcTrack)
    dgvItems.Columns.Add(dcCarrier)
    dgvItems.Columns.Add(dcShipDate)
    dgvItems.Columns.Add(dcTrackingNo)

    dgvItems.Columns("AddTrack").DisplayIndex = 0
    dgvItems.Columns("ViewTrack").DisplayIndex = 1

    For Each dr as DataGridViewRow In dgvItems.Rows
        If Not IsDbNull(dr.Cells("buyout_process")) AndAlso dr.Cells("buyout_process").Value = "Y" Then
        sqlTrack = "ANOTHER SQL COMMAND"
        dtTrack = GetMySQLData(sqlTrack)

        If dtTrack.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            dr.Cells("Carrier").Value = dtTrack.Rows(0).Item("Carrier")
            dr.Cells("ShipDate").Value = dtTrack.Rows(0).Item("ShipDate")
            dr.Cells("TrackingNo").Value = dtTrack.Rows(0).Item("TrackingNo")

            Else 
                Dim cell As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                cell.Value = ""
                dr.Cells("ViewTrack") = cell
            End If
        Else
            Dim cell As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            cell.Value = ""
            dr.Cells("AddTrack") = cell

            cell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            cell.Value = ""
            dr.Cells("ViewTrack") = cell

        End If
    Next

dgvItems.Columns.Remove("buyout_process")
dgvItems.Refresh()
TabControl1.TabPages("tabDetails").Enabled = True
```

Long story short - I retrieve data from a database into a datatable and set that table as the datasource for the DGV.  Then I add 5 columns to the DGV, two of which are button columns (and are move to the first two positions in the DGV).  Then, depending on whether additional data is present, either the data in the additional columns are filled in, or the buttons are replaced by textbox cells, making the buttons disappear and therefore unclickable.

There's nothing wrong with my code, everything works just fine... the second time.  When the code is fired, everything runs as it should and finishes just fine, however, the DGV still displays buttons in both columns and on all rows, regardless of whether or not I replaced those cells with TextBoxCells, and the final column ("buyout_process") is still displayed.

But(!!), if I click back to the main tab, and then back again to the tab with the DGV (forcing the exact same code to run again), the DGV displays everything as it should be (buttons only visible on the correct rows, and the "buyout_process" column removed).

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try dgvItems.Invalidate()?

Comment: I hadn't before, but I just did... still the same result.  Thanks though.